# No me carga el <meta property="og:image" content="img.png">

Tags: html

ayer cambie la imagen que se previsualiza de mi página pero no carga. Cambié el meta **og:image** y el **og:description** al mismo tiempo, pero solo se cambió el **og:description**. Así se muestra cuando quiero compartir el enlace en whatsapp.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Verifiqué la ruta de la imagen y no es el problema.

Si comparto el enlace en instagram y facebook, si se puede ver.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que el inconveniente es solo con whatsapp.

Acá dejo el código del html

```
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="Vení a conocer nuestra variedad en pizzas a la parrilla, tragos y más. ¡Todo acompañado de buena música y la mejor onda!">
    <meta name="keywords" content="parripizzas, pizzeria reconquista, parripizzas reconquista, pizzas a la parrilla, parrilla, pizzas, hamburguesas">
    <meta property="og:site_name" content="Parri Pizzas Reconquista">
    <meta property="og:type" content="website">
    <meta property="og:title" content="Parri Pizzas Reconquista">
    <meta property="og:description" content="Vení a conocer nuestra variedad en pizzas a la parrilla, tragos y más. ¡Todo acompañado de buena música y la mejor onda!">
    <meta property="og:url" content="https://parripizzas.com">
    <meta property="og:image" content="scss/img/wallpaper-parripizzas.png">

    <link rel="icon" href="mini-logo-parripizzas.png">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/style.css">
    <title>Parri Pizzas Reconquista</title>
</head>
```

Comment: ¿La imagen cumple con los requisitos que indica la [documentación](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters/images)? El primer problema pasa porque le estás dando una URL relativa y el FacebookBot es más flojo que una alfombra debajo de una piedra, así que no lo va a resolver. Mira [este ejemplo](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/webmasters#markup)

Comment: Si cumple esos requisitos. Probé enviar el enlace por un mensaje en instagram y ahí si se muestra. Será solo un problema de whatsapp?

Comment: @DaianaPolo, tenes que poner la URL completa a la imagen. Ejemplo: `https://parripizzas.com/scss/img/wallpaper-parripizzas.png`

Comment: Ahí lo cambie como dijiste, todavía no se muestra pero voy a esperar un rato y luego vuelvo a probar.